# AppsScript to change calendar colour dependent on the sender

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I am looking for an Apps Script that will either change the visibility of an event, or if that's not possible then change the colour of an event, where the invite is sent from a specific shared calendar (so a specific calendar ID).  Does anyone know if this is possible?  I am quite new to Apps Script and am specifically struggling with the part that looks at the sender of the event.

Comment: Will the [`getCreators()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event#getcreators) method work for you?

Comment: I'll certainly try it!  Thanks Diego!

Comment: Hi! Please test the method commented by @Diego and write back sharing your findings.